# Как тестировать приложения написанные для Win 10 на Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Пишу приложение под UWP и возникла необходимость собрать пакеты и протестировать все дома на компьютере Win 8.1 как бы это сделать? (Необходимо поставить приложение для его дальнейшего использования, а не для тестирования)

Answer (score 1):

Приложения UWP не работают на ранних версиях ОС. Т.е. чтобы поставить приложение, надо поставить вин 10. 
Почему бы 8.1 и не обновить на 10? Объективных причин чтобы этого не делать на мой взгляд нет.

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно поставить VirtualBox, а туда установить необходимую ОС.

Так же в последних Windows появились встроенные средства виртуализации.

Можно так же вообще установить несколько ОС, а при загрузке ПК выбирать конкретную ОС.

Comment: Я бы хотел поставить туда приложение на всегда а не однажды, минуя Windows   Store...